# Trouble playing mp3 file from raw folder

Tags: android

I wrote my code compiles clean and fine and says no errors. Same code I have used on other apps published on the market. My problem came when I updated the ADT.  I read the posts on cleaning it stage by stage, on getting the newest update available, nothing is working for my app.  It doesn't play the sound in the raw file.  It acts like their is no Raw folder.  It compiles without issue but does not play the mp3.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any logcat messages related to this? Could you post the code you use to read/play the file?

Comment: how do i see the logcat, i just upgraded to indigo trying to fix this problem?

Comment: Go to `DDMS` perspective and `Window -> Show View -> LogCat`

Comment: The logcat does not display anything, did i open the wrong logcat?

Comment: Click your device on the left. It's possible there is no error. Post the code you are having trouble with

Comment: 11-30 14:50:24.855: I/ARMAssembler(51): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001A01_00000000 [ 73 ipp] (98 ins) at [0x415d08:0x415e90] in 4947916 ns

Comment: That line isn't helpful. Try posting some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public class UpdatecodeActivity extends Activity {

```
MediaPlayer mp1, mp2;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.wait);
    mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.primates);

    //Button coding for menu and items 
    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    registerForContextMenu(btn1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    registerForContextMenu(btn2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
}//Closing tag for OnCreate

//OnClick handler for multiple buttons
public void onClick(View v){
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btn1) {
        // action to perform on button 1

         mp1.start();

    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.btn2) {
        // action to perform on button 1

        mp2.start(); 


    }//Closes Onclick Switches
}//Closes onclick
```

Comment: ok found the error, i didnt put a onclicklistener into the app so i could push the button a million times and nothing.  Thanks to your logcat, i would never have thought about it.